# Why can't I render a partial in Exercise 1 of Chapter 11 of Michael Hartl's Rail Tutorial Book?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org, partials

I'm trying to complete [Exercise 1, Chapter 11 of Michael Hartl's Rail Tutorial Book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-micropost_exercises), but when I load the page in a browser I don't see my partials rendered.

[image: screenshot]

The brief is:

> Refactor the Home page to use separate partials for the two branches of the if-else statement.

The homepage template in which I am trying to load partials is as follows:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <% render 'shared/home_logged_in' %>
<% else %>
    <% render 'shared/home_not_logged_in' %>
<% end %>
```

An example of one of the partials that I am trying to load is as follows:

```
<div class="center jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>

  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>

<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"),
            'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

My code is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/MasterRoot24/sample_app) and the changes I have made in an attempt to complete this exercise can be found [here](https://github.com/MasterRoot24/sample_app/commit/2ac24ee035f9b95e37fac5a55d23139e8b168905).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Adding links to your github repository is nice but if you want debugging help you should add the relevant code in the body of the question. It a nice courtesy to people who are prepared to help you and safeguards SO against link rot.

Comment: Understood. Question updated to include the code that I am using. I've also included the brief of the exercise that I am trying to complete, to further avoid link rot (if the link to the tutorial book breaks/changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `<% render 'shared/home_logged_in' %>` instead of `<%= render 'shared/home_logged_in' %>`. You need to print the expression into the page buffer for it be included in the response.

```
<% "I am invisible" %>
<%= "I am not" %>
```

Comment: That was it. I've replaced `<%` with `<%=` and it works now. Thanks!